# Preview images in vim explorer

Tags: vim, file-manager

How can I preview images in `vim`'s explorer (the `:Explore` command)? One of the solutions would be to execute a specific command with the filename under cursor as an argument, but I don't know how to get it. I searched through the help of `:Explore`, but can't find anything that can help. I know I can do this in other file managers, but I want this functionality inside `vim`.

Answer (score 0):

The *netrw* plugin (which provides the `:Explore` command) has a built-in preview (cp. `:help netrw-preview`), which uses Vim's preview window. But of course, most image files are binary, so it probably doesn't make sense to open it in Vim itself; you probably want to open this in an external image viewer (like `eog`).

This is the mapping (in the explorer buffer) that powers the preview:

```
:nmap <buffer> p
n  p           *@:<C-U>call <SNR>731_NetrwPreview(<SNR>731_NetrwBrowseChgDir(1,<SNR>731_NetrwGetWord(),1))<CR>
```

The inner part (`<SNR>731_NetrwBrowseChgDir(1,<SNR>731_NetrwGetWord(),1)`) yields the full path to the current file. You could use that to launch an external viewer:

```
:call system('eog ' . shellescape(<SNR>731_NetrwBrowseChgDir(1,<SNR>731_NetrwGetWord(),1)))
```

Unfortunately, those netrw functions are script-local (and the `<SNR>731` part probably is different on your system), so you'd have to directly modify the netrw plugin to add your "external image preview" shortcut, also because the mapping is not a global one, but specially set up by the plugin for its explorer buffer. I can provide you more details if you decide to follow that route. It's also possible to extend the plugin without modifying it, but that's a lot more work.